# Writing Ints, floats to a text file

Tags: c++

I have a problem.
I want to write Ints and Floats to a text file, but when I try to do this it wonnt work.
When I try it, I get the %d in my text file. Here is a part of my code.

```
void controleformules::on_pushButton_4_clicked()
{
    QString str= ui->textEdit_2->toPlainText();

    QString filename= str+".txt";

    QFile file( filename );

    if ( file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite) )
    {

         QTextStream stream( &file );
         stream << "U heeft nu deze 2 formules gekozen:
              Formule 1: %dx + %dy = %0.1f. 
              Formule 2: %dx + %dy = %d", x1Int, y1Int, r1Int, x2Int, y2Int, r2Int;

         stream << "eerst moet je in beide formules de x of de y elimeneren, wij doen de y eerst";

     }
 }
```

I hope you can help me
Tim Smits

Comment: What are `x1Int`, `y1int`, etc?

Comment: Those are Floats and Ints, sorry my bad for not telling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two **distinct** text systems in C++. One is iostreams, which use inserters:

```
int n = 3;
std::cout << "This is a number: " << n << '\n';
```

The other is `printf` and its relatives; they come from C:

```
int n = 3;
printf("This is a number: %d\n", n);
```

Comment: I have an additional question,
When I want to add a break the << "\n"  does not work.
I hope you can help me with this.

Comment: @user2479441 - you should post a new question, with actual code, and a description of what you expect it to do and what it does.

Comment: @bluefalcon - `"\n"` and `'\n'` both insert a newline into a stream. The latter is slightly more efficient, but they both do the same thing.

Comment: @Pete Becker
Sorry, I will make a new question.

Answer (score 3):

C++ streams don't work with format strings like `printf` does.  Either just *use* printf:

```
sprintf(buffer, "U heeft nu deze 2 formules gekozen: "
                "Formule 1: %dx + %dy = %0.1f. "
                "Formule 2: %dx + %dy = %d", 
                x1Int, y1Int, r1Int, x2Int, y2Int, r2Int);
stream << buffer;
```

or to stay with streams alone:

```
stream << "U heeft nu deze 2 formules gekozen: Formule 1: "
       << x1Int << "x + " << y1Int << "y = " << r1Int << ". Formule 2: "
       << x2Int << "x + " << y2Int << "y = " << r2Int;
```

It is a bit weird that you have a floating point format `%0.1f`, but the variable you're matching it with is called `r1Int`.  Be careful for undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with QTextStream, but this is the full formatting source to get what you want.

```
stream << ("U heeft nu deze 2 formules gekozen: Formule 1: " << x1Int << " + " << y1Int << " = " << r1Int << ". Formule 2: " << x2Int << " + " <<  y2Int << " = " r2Int);
```

This is more cumbersome, but it will get you the formatting you want.

Answer (score 1):

You mare mixing the way you use streams with the way you use `sprintf`.  They are different.

With a stream, you don't use placeholders like `%d` -- you simply insert the values at the point you want them inserted.  Like this:

```
stream 
  << "U heeft nu deze 2 formules gekozen: Formule 1: "
  << x1Int
  << " + " 
  << y1Int 
  << " = "
  << r1Int
  << "." 
  << y2Int
  << " Formule 2: ";
```

..et cetera.